# Android: How to display database data in ListView?

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I've got no clue how to do this...Please help!
I have it all setup as of now to add an athletes name, age, tier, and date added to a database. I wish to add each of these athletes to a listView and be able to click on the name to open another activity which I will create later. I mainly just want to add these names to a listview from my database but don't know how. I have tried to use adapters but to no success.

```
public void onClick_btnDisplayList(View view) {
    // What do I put in this to display what is in my database
}
```

onCreate method:

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
ListView listView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_user);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


}
```

Add to database method:

```
public void onClick_btnAddAthlete(View view) {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    EditText editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);


    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
    db.addContact(new Athlete("Ravi", "20", "2", "10/12/13"));
    db.addContact(new Athlete("Srinivas", "23", "4", "4/2/12"));
    db.addContact(new Athlete("Tommy", "43", "1", "7/11/14"));
    db.addContact(new Athlete("Karthik", "6", "3", "1/3/12"));

    // Reading all contacts
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
    List<Athlete> athletes = db.getAllAthletes();

    for (Athlete cn : athletes) {
        String log = "Id: " + cn.getID() + " ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getAge() +
                " ,Tier: " + cn.getTier() + " ,Date: " + cn.getDate();
        // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Name: ", log);
    }
}
```

Comment: You said using an array adapter didn't work? What wasn't working? Because that seems to be the best solution to me.

Comment: I am 99% sure you have to use adapters with ListViews. I would recommend creating an adapter class and working with it. I can try to type something up when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you need to create a **Custom adapter** for this purpose.
2. Then you need to query your database for fetching the records.(Use `AsyncTask`)
3. Create an `ArrayList` of your `Athlete` class and store the value from db there.
4. Finally set this list to your Custom adapter.

[Creating a Custom Adapter](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)

Answer (score 0):

I will extend on this some more when I get a chance but

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

     private Context context;
     private List<Athlete> athletes;

     public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, List athletes){
         this.context = context;
         this.athletes = athletes;
     }

     @Override
     public int getCount(){
         return athletes.size();
     }

     @Override
     public Athlete getItem(int position){
         return athletes.get(position);
     }

     @Override
     public int getItemId(int position){
         return position;
     }

     @Override
     public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout_name, parent, false);

         // Get views with something like
         // TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);

         Athlete currAthlete = getItem(position);

         // Do what you want with your athlete, like
         // text.setText(currAthlete.getName());
    }
}
```

Then in your Activity

```
listView.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(this, athletes));
```

This isn't a complete answer, but was too long for a comment and I don't have time right now to complete it. It should give you an idea of how to use an adapter.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for here is practically an entire app. I don't mean to scare you, but you need to step back and remember object oriented programming (OOP):

- You need an Athlete class with all the data you want to display for an athlete; which you seem to already have. So good.
- You need a class for getting the data from your database into an ArrayList: `ArrayList<Athlete> mAthletes;` So this class should have a method for getting the data from the db. In that method you need an anonymous asyncTask, which will populate the field `mAthlete` for you. Call this class `AthleteLoader`. Athlete loader should extend Observable so to tell the Activity when the data is loaded. Your Activity class should call this method inside `onCreate` or `onResume` depending on your design. Also you may want to place a check inside the method so that it only queries the db when the ArrayList is empty. Again, you decide based on your design.
- In your Activity class, you need to implement Observer so that when the data is ready from `AthleteLoader`, you can call `notifyObservers()` to broadcast the information.
- Inside your activity class, inside the `update` method (due to Observer), pass the data to the adapter by calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter.
- Inside the adapter you need to grab each athlete from the class `AthleteLoader`. There are many ways for doing this. One way is to simply have `mAthletes` in your adapter point to `mAthletes` in `AthleteLoader`. So that when the data is there, then it's there (excuse the tautology, but here I am assuming you understand OOP and pointers in java). So that the call from the Activity to `notifyDataSetChanged` will be enough.
- Also the adapter should extend the base adapter so that all the methods are populated with `mAthletes`. So for example, `getItem` should simply `return mAthletes.get(location);`

If you are a true newbie this is definitely a lot of information. But then again you are asking for a lot of help with that simple question. So good luck to you and I hope you can use this list to guide you in your quest.